# How is this bitshifting working in this example?

Tags: go, bit, bit-shift

I was going through the `go` tutorial on golang.org and I came across an example that i partially understand...

```
MaxInt uint64     = 1<<64 - 1
```

Now I understand this to be shifting the bit 64 places to the left which would make it a 1 followed by 64 0's.

My question is why is this the max integer that can be achieved in a 64 bit number. Wouldn't the max integer be `111111111....(until the 64th 1)` instead of `100000...(until the 64th one)`?

Comment: `1 << 64 = 10000000000000000` (hex) `1 << 64 - 1 = FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF` (hex) which is the largest *unsigned* 64 bit integer that can be stored in a *twos-compliment* numbering system. (if you are still stuck `1 << 64` is a `65` bit number, not `64`)

Comment: ahh ok so by subtracting 1 you make the 65th bit disappear leaving `111111.....`?

Comment: Yes, you got it! (but leaving `FFFF... (16 hex digits)`, or `1111.... (64 binary 1s`)

Comment: subtraction works the same in any base, just like in base 10 `1000 - 1 = 999`, one digit less.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin isn't two's complement used to represent signed integers specifically? i.e. there's no such thing as an unsigned two's complement numbering system (at least not in the context of binary numbers in programming)? c.f. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement

Comment: *"GCC supports only two's complement integer types, and all bit patterns are ordinary values."* [**See: 4.5 Integers**](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Integers-implementation.html)  It applies to *both*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens here, step by step:

1. Take 1.
2. Shift it to the left 64 bits. This is tricky. The result actually needs 65 bits for representation - namely 1 followed by 64 zeroes. Since we are calculating a 64 bit value here why does this even compile instead of overflowing to 0 or 1 or producing a compile error?
3. It works because the arithmetic used to calculate constants in Go is a bit magic (https://blog.golang.org/constants) in that it has nothing to do whatsoever with the type of the named constant being calculated. You can say `foo uint8 = 1<<415 / 1<<414` and `foo` is now `2`.
4. Subtract 1. This brings us back into 64 bits numbers, as it's actually 11....1 (64 times), which is indeed the maximum value of `uint64`. Without this step, the compiler would complain about us trying to cram 65 bit value into `uint64`.
5. Name the constant `MaxInt` and give it type `uint64`. Success!

The magic arithmetic used to calculate constants still has limitations (obviously). Shifts greater than 500 or so produce funny named `stupid shift` errors.